# Average magnetisation in the Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, partition-function

The Ising Model has energy given by

$$
E=-B \sum_{i} s_{i}-J \sum_{\langle i, j\rangle} s_{i} s_{j}
$$

where $\langle i, j\rangle$ indicates that the second sum is over each pair of nearest neighbours.

Next up in my lecture notes, the lecturer defines the average magnetisation as 
$$
m=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i}\left\langle s_{i}\right\rangle
$$

which evaluates to $$\frac{1}{N \beta} \frac{\partial \log Z}{\partial B}$$

Now my question is shouldn't this be

$$
m=\frac{1}{N} \left\langle \sum_{i} s_{i}\right\rangle
$$

instead as it is defined in the [Stanford notes](http://micro.stanford.edu/~caiwei/me334/Chap12_Ising_Model_v04.pdf) on page 4 or the [MIT notes](http://web.mit.edu/ceder/publications/Ising%20Model.pdf) in slide 5.

I suspect that these two might actually be entirely equivalent but I am not sure how to argue about this. I thought maybe each atom is identical and so the average spin for each particle much be the same by symmetry. However, the interaction between neighbours makes me question if this argument holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expectation values always distribute over sums of random variables (or operators). You don't need to use any symmetry arguments or facts about the specific system.